# How to get a list of coordinates from a KML file in Python

Tags: python, kml

I have a KML file with the following structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?><kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
<name>Test KML</name>
<description><![CDATA[<p>This is a test version.</p>]]></description>
<Style id="spstyle7">
    <IconStyle>
        <color>ff4DF6D8</color>
        <Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-blank.png</href></Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff4DF6D8</color>
        <width>4</width>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>
<Folder>
    <name>Track1</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
            <name>Test1</name>
            <description><![CDATA[test1]]></description>
            <Placemark>
                <name>test1</name>
                <description><![CDATA[test1]]></description>
                <MultiGeometry>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            11.000,4.000 11.000,3.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            11.000,4.000 12.000,4.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            12.000,5.000 12.000,4.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
                </MultiGeometry>
            </Placemark>
</Folder>
<Style id="spstyle7">
    <IconStyle>
        <color>ff4DF6D8</color>
        <Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-blank.png</href></Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff4DF6D8</color>
        <width>4</width>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>
<Folder>
    <name>Track2</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
            <name>Test2</name>
            <description><![CDATA[test2]]></description>
            <Placemark>
                <name>test2</name>
                <description><![CDATA[test2]]></description>
                <MultiGeometry>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            8.000,8.000 8.000,7.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            8.000,7.000 11.000,6.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            9.000,1.000 10.000,1.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
                </MultiGeometry>
            </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

I want to get all the coordinates inside the *coordinates* tag, either into a list or into a list of lists (one for each folder).

As a start, I wrote the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("test.kml")
root = tree.getroot()
results = root.findall('Folder')
textnumbers = [r.find('Placemark/LineString/coordinates').text for r in results]
print textnumbers
```

But it returns an empty list. If I try to get only the *Folder* names, with the code below:

```
for folder in root.findall('Folder'):
    name = folder.find('name')
    print name
```

I also get an empty string. Why the heck doesn't the parser find the *Folder* tag? Any hints?

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: @Wondercricket ... that is ill-advised. Namespaces should not have to be removed for XML parsing.

Comment: And I fail to see what namespaces have to do with my problem.

Comment: It is exactly your problem as you have a namespace with undeclared prefix but do not use in parsing and hence no results!

Comment: Sure, I have not paid due attention to it. Thanks!

Comment: Did you removed namespaces from the documents? If there are namespaces, you can read the XML easily

Comment: @Pant ... Wondercricket's previous comment (now deleted) made same observation. Please see my reply, first comment here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I found a fine solution here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89543/get-points-from-a-kml-linestring.

Modyfing my code accordingly:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("test.kml")
root = tree.getroot()

lineStrings = tree.findall('.//{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1}LineString')

for attributes in lineStrings:
    for subAttribute in attributes:
        if subAttribute.tag == '{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1}coordinates':
            print subAttribute.tag, subAttribute.text
```

I have been able to retrieve all the coordinate data.

Other possible solutions (not tested) can also be found here: https://programmingadvent.blogspot.com.br/2013/06/kmzkml-file-parsing-with-python.html and here: http://gsp.humboldt.edu/olm_2016/courses/GSP_318/04_3_2_Parsing_XML.html

Best regards,

Comment: Though you grabbed code and found your answer. The real issue is you need to explicitly declare the namespace (`xmlns`) as done here within the braces `{...}` and as shown in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces). Also, you did not parse down to the *LineString* node with double `.//` XML operator to get all *coordinates*.

Comment: Parfait, I did not understand. The above code iactually gets all coordinates inside the 'coordinates' tag, which is what I want. And it explicitly declares the namespace within braces.

Comment: @maurobio I have added an answer that should address your issue. Take a look into it. Thanks.

Comment: This solution is not elegant, but at least it provides a way to navigate around the KML file and extract content without installing any library. If you know the relevant tags, you can get anything you want, it just produces cluttered code. Still worked for me and save me some time.

Answer (score 0):

Your root is `kml` node not `Document` node as you assume

When you do `tree.getroot()` you grab `kml` node. In this case if you just change your code to include `Document` as child node of root it should work.

Actually only line to change should be this:

```
result = root.findall('Document/Folder')
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it does not work. I still got an empty list.